# How to disable SSL session resumption on client side completely?

Tags: session, authentication, ssl, openssl

I'm using OpenSSL 1.0.2g. In my client I would like to disable SSL session resumption completely (for test purposes).

I do prior to connection, after creating SSL_CTX:

```c
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);
```

But what I saw in traffic capture - is that my client always do session reuse with sending non-empty session ID. And server does accept it.

How can I disable SSL session resumption completely?

More expanded code snippet:

```c
SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()))
SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode(ctx, SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF);
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKET);
SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 0);
SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Any required steps are missing?

Comment: What does `ldd <your prog>` return? The reason I ask Is many distors provide OpenSSL 1.0.1. Though you are compiling and linking against OpenSSL 1.0.2, at runtime you may get a downlevel 1.0.1 load. OpenSSL 1.01. and 1.0.2 are binary compatible, so you will likely never know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting auto-retry:

```
SSL_CTX_set_mode(ctx, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);
```

Per the [documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_mode.html):

> **SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY**
>
> Never bother the application with retries if the transport is
>   blocking. If a renegotiation take place during normal operation, a
>   SSL_read or SSL_write would return with -1 and indicate the need to
>   retry with SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. In a non-blocking environment
>   applications must be prepared to handle incomplete read/write
>   operations. In a blocking environment, applications are not always
>   prepared to deal with read/write operations returning without success
>   report. **The flag SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY will cause read/write operations
>   to only return after the handshake and successful completion**.

That implies that auto-renegotiation will happen silently, without the application using the OpenSSL libraries being aware.  See [the documentation for `SSL_write()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_write.html):

> If the underlying BIO is blocking, SSL_write() will only return, once
>   the write operation has been finished or an error occurred, **except
>   when a renegotiation take place**, in which case a SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
>   may occur. This behaviour can be controlled with the
>   SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY flag of the SSL_CTX_set_mode call.

Such "silent" renegotiations *may* explain your observed behavior, and if so, not using `SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY` may solve your issue.

OpenSSL is an extremely complex tool with, in my opinion, poorly-documented behavior of many options.  For an all-too-relevant example, what does, "This behaviour can be controlled with the SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY flag of the SSL_CTX_set_mode call."  Controlled *how*?  It's *implied* that using `SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY` allows for silent renegotation and therefor session reuse, but it's never explicitly stated.

Along the same lines, one of [the many options for `SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode.html) may be relevant:

> In order to reuse a session, a client must send the session's id to
>   the server. It can only send exactly one id. The server then either
>   agrees to reuse the session or it starts a full handshake (to create a
>   new session).
>
> A server will lookup up the session in its internal session storage.
>   If the session is not found in internal storage or lookups for the
>   internal storage have been deactivated
>   (SSL_SESS_CACHE_NO_INTERNAL_LOOKUP), the server will try the external
>   storage if available.

So, does

> **SSL_SESS_CACHE_OFF**
>
> No session caching for client or server takes place.

disable the use of the *internal* cache?  To me, the implication is that it *doesn't*.

Comment: What does this have to do with session resumption?

Comment: @EJP - The documentation I linked implies silent renegotiation of the session, and thus could cause the OP's noted session re-use.  See https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_write.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle - Good observation. You should probably state the connection between the two in the answer because its not readily apparent. It may also avoid future downvotes; and someone may retract their downvote.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing anything wrong?

I think you must be doing something wrong when looking at the traffic or there is an important part of the code which you don't show. By default the client will not resume any sessions at all simply because it does not know which session should be resumed. From the documentation of [SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_session_cache_mode.html):

> SSL_SESS_CACHE_CLIENT
>   ... As there is no reliable way for the OpenSSL library to know whether a session should be reused or which session to choose (due to the abstract BIO layer the SSL engine does not have details about the connection), **the application must select the session to be reused by using the SSL_set_session function**...